# Installing Windows 7 on a new Ubuntu computer

Tags: windows-7

I just received a new Alienware computer with Ubuntu pre-installed, since updated to version 12.04.  I would like to install Windows 7 or 8 (I have installation discs for both) to run some programs.  Any advice for a Ubuntu novice on how to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should first make a separate partition using **Gparted**. It is a good tool to create/add/delete/manage partitions of your **HDD**. Since you got pre-installed Ubuntu, It may not be installed already.

Open a terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) then execute following:

```
    $ sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Open gparted from dash and make partition as required. **Gparted** so easy to use that any one can grab it. I prefer you to install Windows 7. It is possible that after installing Windows, you will not be able to access Ubuntu. But don't worry, you can fix this issue very easily, if you have a bootable CD of Ubuntu.

For more information you can prefer following link:

[How to dual boot Windows 7 x64 and Ubuntu 13.04 x64 as BIOS, not EFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336597/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-x64-and-ubuntu-13-04-x64-as-bios-not-efi/336783#336783)

You have to follow the preferred answer(i,e answer which is marked as **tick**).

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer) for linking to specific answers (i.e. you get the URL by using the 'share' button).